r facet wrap maps ggplot
I have an issue with using geom_sf and facet_wrap.
Below is a reproducible example. When I use 'ct_sf1` I dont see a boundary of my first geom_sf.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(tigris)

ct_sf <- tigris::county_subdivisions(state = "09", cb = T, class = "sf")

ct_sf1 <- ct_sf %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(group = as.character(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1)))

ggplot(ct_sf1) +
  geom_sf(fill = "gray95", color = "gray50", size = 0.5) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = group),inherit.aes = F) +
  facet_wrap(~group) 


However when I use the following code, with ct_sf in first geom_sf and ct_sf1 in second geom_sf it works, not sure what could be causing the first code to not work.
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = ct_sf,fill = "gray95", color = "gray50", size = 0.5) +
  geom_sf(data = ct_sf1,aes(fill = group)) +
  facet_wrap(~group) 



In the first code, the second geom_sf overlaps the first one because it applied to the same data, then facet_wrap splits the data by the groups.
In the second code, facet_wrap splits only the ct_sf1 object, and the first object is drawn on all facets.
By the way, you can faster the groups generation without using rowwise:
ct_sf1 <- ct_sf %>% 
    mutate(group = as.character(sample(LETTERS[1:4], nrow(.), replace = T)))


Thank you. If I use the following code, I still don’t get the boundaries: two separate geom_sf but same data: ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = ct_sf1,fill = "gray95", color = "gray50", size = 0.5) +
geom_sf(data = ct_sf1,aes(fill = group)) +
facet_wrap(~group)

I believe ggplot understands that both geoms applied to the same data, and overlaps the first layer by second. Even if you duplicate the object with ct_sf0 <- ct_sf1 and use ct_sf0 for the first geom, you still get the same results, because new object will have the same address (if not modified).

Check this similar question with answer using the same approach and in your second code.
